# How to remove untapped remote notifications from server

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

How can I remove remote notifications from iOS notification center **before opening app** or **user tapping them**?

I searched a lot and found nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have to set badge account to 0!